# Android SQLite Database Update

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a pre-established SQLite Database in my application. It has a table with rows about 20 rows of text. I want to be able to add additional rows to the table without deleting all of the previous information. The only way I have seen which would allow me to do this is to delete all of the previous databases and then recreate it with the new rows. There must be a better way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your question seems to be missing something.  Why can't you just INSERT the new rows into the existing database?

Comment: I think if you don't execute any scripts in SQLLiteOpenHelper onCreate(..) that should keep your pre-established DB as it is.

Comment: @user.you can directly use INSERT INTO for entering new rows OR you can use ContentProviders for inserting in the Table...Totally depends on your choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you confusing rows with columns?

If you really do mean rows then as antlersoft points out, using the SQL INSERT INTO statement will simply add a new row to a table without affecting any existing table data. This is one of the most basic and commonly used SQL statements.

If you actually mean you need to add columns then use the SQL ALTER TABLE statement.

See..

[SQL INSERT INTO statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

[SQL ALTER TABLE statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. And you were right, I wanted to insert an additional column I believe.

Comment: I figured as much. Just think of it that columns can hold up the roof of a building and you'll remember which is which. You can pretty much do anything with a DB without having to destroy the existing data. Keep that site bookmarked it's pretty good as a quick reference.

Answer (score 0):

The Android framework, as it relates to SQLite (using a SQLiteOpenHelper) provides two distinct methods for handling database lifecycles - `onCreate()`, used when the database needs to be created from scratch, and `onUpgrade(<database>, int oldVersion, int newVersion)` for handling updates.  You can specify the "new" version number in the constructor for the superclass of your SQLiteOpenHelper, and the framework knows to call `onUpgrade()` based on this parameter and the internal version # in the actual sqlite database.

So, to modify your database during a version change just override onUpgrade() and run whatever SQLite stuff that you need.